# IDE-alike Find Usages

Tags: ctags, ide

I use [exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net) to find definitions of classes, methods and the like. Which packages find the usages of a specific tag? A `git grep` does not work for me as the result is way to big; many method names are used in multiple locations but the corresponding tags are not related. Thanks for your help!

Comment: With which language are you working with? BTW, exuberant ctags is no longer maintained, you should move to [universal ctags](https://github.com/universal-ctags) instead.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, thanks! And it's using git now! Currently I work with ruby (and [grape](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape)).

Comment: [GNU Global](https://www.gnu.org/software/global/) apparently comes with ruby support. GNU Global provides a cscope interface, `gtags-cscope` which can find usages. See `:h cscope` for Vim usage of cscope